# How to test for CDATA value of an element using Dom4j?

Tags: java, cdata, dom4j

Does anybody have an idea how to find out whether an element contains `<![CDATA[ text ]]>` or not ? I search through the dom4j API and Jaxen and I can't find how to do that... If I retrieve the text, it the cdata wrapper is trimmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can still do this.

```
public boolean isCDATA(org.dom4j.Node node) {
  for (org.dom4j.Node n : node.content()) {
    if (org.w3c.dom.Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE == n.getNodeType()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You are right, but it must be elements, because the method is in AbstractBranch class.

Answer (score 1):

The method:

```
Node.asXML()
```

returns the entire element with its value unmodified by anything.

So if you have:

```
<nodes>
  <node><![CDATA[value]]></node>
</nodes>
```

Calling the text methods will return "value", but calling "asXML()" will return:

```
<node><![CDATA[value]]></node>
```

From there, I guess you can do a String search for the CDATA tag.

Answer (score 0):

http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Node.html#getNodeType%28%29

will this work?

```
public short getNodeType()
```

Returns the code according to the type of node. This makes processing nodes polymorphically much easier as the switch statement can be used instead of multiple if (instanceof) statements.

Returns: a W3C DOM complient code for the node type such as ELEMENT_NODE or ATTRIBUTE_NODE

Comment: you ask me :-) ? It wont, it returns type of the element... I'm concerned with its value

Comment: You can use it, but it has to be in conjunction with the content() method.